# Setting an immutable instance variable for an object from a property

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, getter-setter

I wish to define an Atom class that can be intialised by providing a atomic label and a vector and then having the atomic mass and number of electrons interannly assigned on initialisation or whenver the objects atomic label is changed.

```
periodic_table = {
    'H': {'Z': 1.008, 'nelec': 1},
    'C': {'Z': 12.011, 'nelec': 6},
    'N': {'Z': 14.007, 'nelec': 7},
    'O': {'Z': 15.999, 'nelec': 8},
    'S': {'Z': 32.06, 'nelec': 16},
    'Br': {'Z': 79.904, 'nelec': 35},
    'I': {'Z': 126.90, 'nelec': 53}
}


class Atom:

    def __init__(self, label: str, vector: list):
        self.__label = label
        self.vector = vector
        self.__Z = None
        self.__nelec = None


    def __lookup_info(self):
        atom_info = periodic_table[self.__label]
        self.__Z = atom_info['Z']
        self.__nelec = atom_info['nelec']

    @property
    def label(self):
        return self.__label

    @label.setter
    def label(self, value):
        if type(value) != str:
            raise Exception("Atomic labels must be a string")
        else:
            value = value.upper()
            self.__label = value
            __lookup_info(self)
            # lookup info and set z/nelec

    @property
    def Z(self):
        return self.__Z

    @property
    def nelec(self):
        return self.__nelec
```

However I get the following error,

```
>>>atom1 = Atom('C', [0,1,1])
>>>atom1.Z   # here the value is None and is not assigned by __lookup_info() on init
>>>atom1.label = 'H'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xxx", line 95, in label
    self.__label = value
NameError: name 'lookup_info' is not defined
```

I wish the following functionality,

```
>>>atom1 = Atom('C', [0,1,1])
>>>atom1.Z
    12.011
>>>atom1.nelec
    6
>>>atom1.label = 'H'
>>>atom1.Z
    1.008
>>>atom1.nelec
    1
```

I only want the user to be able to change the values of `Z` and `nelec` by setting a new label. I do not understand why my call to the hidden method `__lookup_info()` does not work whenever I set the property label. I am new to OOP, thanks for any help.

Comment: Typo.  You meant `self.__lookup_info()`.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks. It is not clear to me why, that is not how I normally call methods? I realise I need self.__lookup_info() in the __init__ method for it to work when first initialised too.

Comment: That is how you call Python methods.  Python's name lookup does not check for members, the way C++ does.  A bare name has to be a local, an argument, or a global.  The name `__lookup_info` does not exist.  It's just a member of `self`.